# MEF - Can I create instances and have them automatically Composed inside MEF?

Tags: c#, .net, mef, .net-4.0

As I understand, in order for Import/Export attributes to be correctly connected to each other, I have to call `compositionContainerInstance.Compose(...)` with each new instance that has these attributes.

Is it possible to have this happening automatically, so I don't have to do it whenever I create a new instance of some composable  class?

This would be an example, although lengthly, it abstracts the problem I have.

```
public class Worker1
{
    [Import(typeof(IDataProvider))]
    public IDataProvider DataProvider;

    public Worker2 second;
    //use data provider to perform logic
}

public class Worker2
{
    [Import(typeof(IDataProvider))]
    public IDataProvider DataProvider;

    //use data provider to perform logic
}

[Export(typeof(IDataProvider))]
public class GeoDataProvider : IDataProvider
{
    //implements logic
}

public class Container
{
    private Worker1 t1;
    public void Init()
    {
        AggregateCatalog cat = new AggregateCatalog();
        cat.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
        cat.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog("."));

        CompositionContainer c = new CompositionContainer(cat);
        c.ComposeParts(new GeoDataProvider(), this);
    }

    public void PerformLogic()
    {
        t1 = new Worker1;
        //here it fails because I need c.ComposeParts(t1):
        t1.DoSomethingWithProvider();
        //but even if I do c.ComposeParts(t1), still the t1.second.DataProvider will be null
        //how to avoid this?
    }
}
```

What I'm hoping for is a way to freely create new instances of Worker1/Worker2 without needing to know that they have to be composed before usage. Is that feasible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone has to know that they need composed.

If you're going to freely create Worker1 and Work2 instances rather than letting MEF create them then you have to also give MEF a chance to satisfy the imports of new instances or as you've discovered, the IDataProvider field is never filled out.

Here's an example where you just let MEF create the classes as needed.  Only one 'ComposeParts' call is needed to get everything setup.

```
[Export]
public class Worker1
{
  [Import]
  public IDataProvider DataProvider;

  [Import]
  public Worker2 second;

  //use data provider to perform logic
  public void DoSomethingWithProvider() {
    }
}

[Export]
public class Worker2
{
  [Import]
  public IDataProvider DataProvider;

  //use data provider to perform logic
}

[Export( typeof( IDataProvider ) )]
public class GeoDataProvider : IDataProvider
{
  //implements logic
}

public class Container
{
  [Import]
  private Worker1 t1;

  public void Init()
  {
    AggregateCatalog cat = new AggregateCatalog();
    cat.Catalogs.Add( new AssemblyCatalog( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() ) );
    cat.Catalogs.Add( new DirectoryCatalog( "." ) );

    CompositionContainer c = new CompositionContainer( cat );
    c.ComposeParts( this );
  }

  public void PerformLogic()
  {
    t1.DoSomethingWithProvider();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really a great answer. Unfortunately for me, some of my workers are actually UserControls (instantiated by designer), so I have to add some logic inside each of the nested control to Compose such instances. Thanks again! I'm really getting to understand this MEF now :)